# No Output from views.py file after getting POST from template file (Django)

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I have been trying to get details filled in a form,back in a python file using django. Everything seems fine but the form details are not getting displayed in the terminal.

**views.py** file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basicapp import forms
# Create your views here. 
def index(request):
return render(request,'basicapp/index.html')

def form_name_view(request):
    form = forms.FormName()
    if request == "POST":
        form = forms.FormName(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            #DO SOMETHING
            print("Validation SUCCESS")
            print("NAME: " + form.cleaned_data['name'])
            print("EMAIL: " + form.cleaned_data['email'])
            print("AVANODA KARUTHTHU: " + form.cleaned_data['text'])


    return render(request,'basicapp/form_page.html', {'form' : form } )
```

**form_page.html** file : ( I have removed the Bootstrap CDNs )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Forms</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">                                                                                  
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "jumbotron">
            <h2> Fill out the form </h2>
            <form method="POST" action = "">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you sure that the data you have entered gets validated? Can you see the
`print("Validation SUCCESS")` on terminal? otherwise you should display the validation errors in the form, to get feedback where the validation fails.

Comment: No, the validation line didn't show up either.

I added an else condition to check that now. 


else:
            print("Not Validated")

This didn't show any output either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction:

`if request.method == "POST":` under `index` function

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: FOUND THE SOLUTION. Please Refer to the attached image.